# Error while getting values between dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to get a chart date vs number of patients .I am trying to make a chart using MS Chart in asp.net where I get date on x axis and number of patients on y axis. 
I am accepting from date and to date as input. I want number of patients between these 2 dates on each date between from and to date. I am trying something as follows

```
select 
convert(varchar,creation_Date,105) as 'creation_Date',
count(Pat_ID)
FROM Patient_Ref_master
where         
 (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date,111)  BETWEEN '2013/07/23' AND '2013/07/25')

group by Pat_ID
```

but giving me an error of

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Where I am going wrong.? Please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: Why, why, why are you converting to a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also have Creation_Date in the group By clause. Following is the correct query:

```
    select 
convert(varchar,creation_Date,105) as 'creation_Date',
count(Pat_ID)
FROM Patient_Ref_master
where         
 (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date,111)  BETWEEN '2013/07/23' AND '2013/07/25')

group by creation_Date
```

Comment: too good Sonam...It worked. Can you please tell me where I was going wrong.?

Comment: Instead of Pat_Id, you should have Creation_Date in the group by clause.

Answer (score 3):

Group by `creation_Date` instead of `Pat_ID`

Answer (score 1):

You want to count patients on a date, so the *date* needs to be in the `group by` clause.  However, you need to be sure it really is a `date` and not a `datetime` for what you are doing.  The following uses your preferred format:

```
select convert(varchar,creation_Date, 105) as 'creation_Date',
       count(Pat_ID) as Numpateitns
FROM Patient_Ref_master
where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date, 111)  BETWEEN '2013/07/23' AND '2013/07/25'
group by convert(varchar,creation_Date, 105)
```

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't group by Pat_ID, you want to group by creation_Date, or your expression that is creation_Date.  Also, I wouldn't convert your dates to varchars in your where clause.  Just keep them as date times.

```
select 
convert(varchar,creation_Date,105) as 'creation_Date',
count(Pat_ID)
FROM Patient_Ref_master
where Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date >= convert(datetime,'2013/07/23') 
AND Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date < dateadd(day,1,convert(datetime,'2013/07/25'))
group by convert(varchar,creation_Date,105)
```